# Is there any way to control ShadcnUI Accordion "open" and "close" functionality using value from the useState in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, accordion, shadcnui

```
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionContent,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/accordion";


interface chapterProps{
  selectedChapter:number;
  setSelectedChapter:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
  chapters:any;
}

export default function Chapters(props: chapterProps) {
  console.log("whats in selected chapter", props?.selectedChapter);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-4">
        {props?.chapters?.map((value: any, index: number) => {
          console.log("whats in chapter map", value);
          return (
            <Accordion
              type="single"
              collapsible
              className="w-full bg-white p-4"
              key={index}
              defaultValue={`item-${props?.selectedChapter}`}
            >
              <AccordionItem value={`item-${index}`} key={index}>

                <AccordionTrigger>
                  <div className="w-full text-left flex flex-col space-y-4">
                    <p className="mx-0 text-[#04445E] font-semibold text-2xl">
                      {value?.chaptername}
                    </p>
                    </>)}
                  </div>
                </AccordionTrigger>

                <AccordionContent key={index}>
                  {value?.chapterContent &&
                    value?.chapterContent?.map((content: any, i: number) => {
                      return (
                          <div className="flex space-y-6 flex-col">
                            <p className="text-2xl text-[#011E29]">
                              {content.name}
                            </p>
                            <div className="flex space-x-4 text-[#011E29]">
                              <p className="">{content.type}</p>
                              <p>{content.time}</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  
                </AccordionContent>

              </AccordionItem>
            </Accordion>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Above is my code where I am trying to control ShadcnUI Accordion "open" and "close" using a state variable called "selectedChapter",
I'm able to set the default AccordionItem open (i,e. "item-0") because default value of my state variable is also 0 but when state variable value changes (example: selectedChapter = 2) after the initial rendering, the AccordionItem with value "item-2" doesn't open

Note: here I'm passing "selectedChapter" state as props from parent component and most of the time it is controlled by parent component itself, Yes i can use "setSelectedChapter" from this component but my concern is with state change from parent component.

Thanks for helping:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RadixUI, The headless UI behind Shadcn/ui, You can make the accordion conrolled by the `value` and `onValueChange` props.

```js
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionContent,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/accordion";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("1");

  return (
    <Accordion type="single" value={value} onValueChange={setValue}>
      {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i) => (
        <AccordionItem key={i} value={i.toString()}>
          <AccordionTrigger>Trigger {i}</AccordionTrigger>
          <AccordionContent>Content {i}</AccordionContent>
        </AccordionItem>
      ))}
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

The state type depends on Accordion's `type` prop. When `type="single"`, the state is of type `string`. When using `type="multiple"` the state will be `string[]`.

In your component, you need two things:

Move the `<Accordion>` wrapper arround the loop, so it can controll all accordions. currently in your implementation every item has its own state. and change `defaultValue` to `value` and `onValueChange`

```js
export default function Chapters(props: chapterProps) {
  const [collabsed, setCollabsed] = useState(props.selectedChapter);

  return (
    <div className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-4">
      <Accordion
        type="single"
        collapsible
        className="w-full bg-white p-4"
        key={index}
        value={`item-${collabsed}`}
        onValueChange={(value) => setCollabsed(value)}
      >
        {props?.chapters?.map((value: any, index: number) => {
          return (
            <AccordionItem value={`item-${index}`} key={index}>
              <AccordionTrigger>
                <div className="w-full text-left flex flex-col space-y-4">
                  <p className="mx-0 text-[#04445E] font-semibold text-2xl">
                    {value?.chaptername}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </AccordionTrigger>

              <AccordionContent key={index}>
                {value?.chapterContent &&
                  value?.chapterContent?.map((content: any, i: number) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="flex space-y-6 flex-col">
                        <p className="text-2xl text-[#011E29]">
                          {content.name}
                        </p>
                        <div className="flex space-x-4 text-[#011E29]">
                          <p className="">{content.type}</p>
                          <p>{content.time}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
              </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionItem>
          );
        })}
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had to make some more changes but your answer helped me to understand what exactly i need to do. Thank you :)